# Prove that all complex functions with $|f(z)| \geq 1$ are constant. (without using Liouville's theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis

It is only given that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the complex plane.

Comment: Liouville theorem?

Comment: is there another way to prove it?

Comment: You can use the Maximum Modulus Principle and the Identity Theorem for holomorphic functions to finish the job too, but it takes a longer route than just invoking Liouville's Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is entire and $|f(z)| \ge 1$ for all $z$, then $g:=1/f$ is entire and  $|g(z)| \le 1$ for all $z$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: yes, Liouville's theorem does the work, i was wondering if there was another way to prove it, a more intuitive one.